# filtering items with jquery based on categories (AND relation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, relationship

I'm stuck on what seems, at first glance, to be simple problem.

For demonstrational purposes, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YANbM/3/).

**The problem:**

I have a lot of categories (represented as fieldsets with checkboxes, in production about 20) and a list of items. I need to filter the items based on the selection a user does in the way, that the relation of the categories to each another is the **AND** operator.

**Example**

The categories are:

1. *color* with [red,blue]
2. *shape* with [circle,square,free]
3. *label* with [lbl1,lbl2,lbl3]

The items are:

1. *item1* with [red,circle,lbl1]
2. *item2* [red,circle,lbl3]

input/selections:

1. *[red]* and *[circle]*
2. *[red]* and *[circle]* and *[lbl1]*
3. *[red,blue]* and *[circle]* and *[lbl1]*

expected results:

1. *[item1]* and *[item2]* should be shown
2. *[item1]* should be shown only
3. *[item1]* should be shown only

algorithm:

At this point I'm struggling :/

(if the item has a property, that is selected in the first category) AND (if the item has a property, that is selected in the second category) AND (...)

**the final question**

What could be such an algorithm in javascript/jquery look like, that is working in a dynamic way. I don't want to write hundreds of if-then-else statements for the AND relation.

**Code**

*Checkboxes*

```
<div class="block" id="selectionGuide" data-guide="products">    
<fieldset id="color" class="checkbox_container">
    <legend>Color</legend>
    <ul class="checkbox_list">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="color1" value="red"><label for="color1">Red</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="color2" value="blue"><label for="color2">Blue</label></li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<!-- some more fieldsets with checkboxes -->
</div>
```

*Items*

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="productItem" data-properties="red circle lbl1">
        <p>Item 1</p>
            <div class="productItemDetails">
                <ul>
                    <li>red</li>
                    <li>circle</li>
                    <li>label 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- a lot more items -->
</div>
```

*data-group attribute*

This is supposed to be helpful to distinguish between a category, that has no selected checkboxes. Should save some time for the lookups.

```
$('[data-properties~=' + $(this).val() + ']').each(function() {                
        if ($(this).attr('data-group') === undefined) {
            $(this).attr('data-group', group);
        } else if ($(this).attr('data-group').indexOf(group) >= 0) {
            if ($('#' + group).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length <= 0) {
                bla = $(this).attr('data-group').replace(' ' + group, '');
                $(this).attr('data-group', bla);
            }
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-group', $(this).attr('data-group') + ' ' + group);
        }
    });
```

*1st possible way to filter the items based on jquery selectors, but don't know, how to create those selectors dynamically*

```
// example selector for Item 1 with properties [red,circle,lbl1]
$('[data-properties~=red][data-properties~=circle][data-properties~=lbl1]').show();
// example selector for Item 5 with properties [red,circle,lbl3]
$('[data-properties~=red][data-properties~=circle][data-properties~=lbl3]').show();
```

*2nd possible way to filter for each item ... also don't know how to write the logic :/*

```
products.filter(function() {
        /** 
         * for each product:
         * - take each data-group and lookup for checked boxes
         * - if for a data-group at least ONE data-property of the checked boxes match AND at least the properties match in all the other data-groups, too
         */

        // good logic/algorithm is needed :/
        if ($(this).is('[data-group]')) {
            // split the data-groups into separated strings
            groups = $(this).attr('data-group').split(' ');

            // a way to look for the checked boxes, but dont know what i should to here :/
            for (i=0; i<groups.length; i++) {
                $('#' + groups[i] + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
            }
        }

        // example for most simple evaluation... attention with the "search" string. should be splitted up, to be not restricted to the word order
        if ($(this).attr('data-properties').search('red circle lb1') >= 0) { return true; }

    }).show();
```

Comment: I have the same question - did you manage to solve it?